# r and ggplot2: plot boolean values for a series of days, each entry should get their own y position

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following dataframe which describes for 5 consecutive days if a certain behavior occured for a certain person. Later there will be 5 persons and 28 days, but this little example should be sufficient to show what I want to achieve.

```
persons <- data.frame(
  person1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
  person2 =  c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
  person3 =  c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
  day  = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)
```

I now want to use ggplot2 to plot this, so the number of the day is put on the x axis. Each of the three persons should get their own y axis position (i.e. person 1 on top, then person 2, and person 3 at the bottom) and get their own color. for each of the days if the value is TRUE, there should be a point filled in the persons's color, otherwise nothing. So for example for person 2, there should be points at X position 3, 4 and 5.

If used smallest examples with ggplot2 before, but have only plotted numbers before. So how do I control the y axis position, so all measurements of person 2 are put in the same y axis position, and how do I control the filled points, so that they are only there if the value is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
persons %>% gather(variable, value, -day) %>% filter(value==TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(day, variable, col=variable)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

**[EDIT]**
Try this:

```
tdf <- persons %>% gather(variable, value, -day) 
tdf %>% filter(value==TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(day, variable, col=variable)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(factor(tdf$variable))))
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way to modify your solution so person1 is at the top instead of the bottom?

Comment: Edited the post as per your requirement